# How to use GetActiveUniform?

Tags: c#, opengl, sharpgl

Generally, question is in header.

I cannot understand how to use `GetActiveUniform` function.

```
public void GetActiveUniform(uint program, 
                             uint index, 
                             int bufSize, 
                             int[] length, 
                             int[] size, 
                             uint[] type, 
                             string name);
```

My attempt looks like this (everything is compiled and linked):

```
        int[] numberOfUniforms = new int[1];
        Gl.GetProgram(programId, ProgramParameter.ActiveUniforms, numberOfUniforms);

        int[] uniformNameMaxLength = new int[1];
        Gl.GetProgram(programId, ProgramParameter.ActiveUniformMaxLength, uniformNameMaxLength);

        int unifromCount = numberOfUniforms[0];

        for (uint i = 0; i < unifromCount; i++)
        {
            var uniformSize = new int[1];
            var unifromLength = new int[1];
            var uniformType = new uint[1];
            string uniformName = "";

            Gl.GetActiveUniform(programId, i, uniformNameMaxLength[0], unifromLength, uniformSize, uniformType, uniformName);
        }
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 150 core

in vec3 in_Position;
out vec3 pass_Color;
uniform vec3 color;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = vec4(in_Position, 1.0);
    pass_Color = color;
}
```

After call I get proper uniformSize, length and type, but not name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of OpenGL usage, you're doing this correctly. The problem comes from the SharpGL bindings you are using. Since the last parameter is declared to be of type `string` and strings are (mostly) immutable in .NET, the function has no way to output the name to you. Short of modifying the bindings yourself, you have two options:

- Check if SharpGL offers another overload of `GetActiveUniform` which takes a mutable object as the name parameter, such as a `StringBuilder`, a `char[]` or maybe even an `out string` (by reference).
- Use another bindings library. OpenTK is a really good, clean and well-maintained one. It uses `ref` parameters instead of having you create tons of one-element arrays. I highly recommend it.

Comment: In fact, passing an immutable string to GetActiveUniform will corrupt the runtime.